# Something sends email to OpenDKIM even after purging it

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, opendkim

I can't send email from my server using Postfix. The `/var/log/mail.log` has:

```
postfix/local[1803]: 59367CDB9: to=<opendkim@example.com>, orig_to=<opendkim>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /run/opendkim/Maildir/tmp/1704452581.P1803.example.com: Permission denied)
postfix/bounce[1805]: 59367CDB9: sender non-delivery notification: 5BD0ECDB3
postfix/qmgr[1731]: 59367CDB9: removed

postfix/qmgr[1731]: 5BD0ECDB3: from=<>, size=2835, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/local[2352]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=114/120: create maildir file /run/opendkim/Maildr/tmp/1704452581.P2352.example.com: Permission denied
postfix/local[2352]: warning: perhaps you need to create the maildirs in advance
postfix/local[2352]: 5BD0ECDB3: to=<opendkim@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /run/opendkim/Maildir/tmp/1704452581.P2352.example.com: Permission denied)
postfix/qmgr[1731]: 5BD0ECDB3: removed
```

To reflect more, I tried to run Dovecot + OpenDKIM + Postfix on my server. After a daunting time the ISP admitted that port 25 is actually filtered, thus I purged Dovecot and OpenDKIM and reinstalled Postfix. Still, even after the purge, `/var/log/mail.log` shows that something is sending mail to the `opendkim` user.

`postconf -n` shows:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`. The logs indicate `postfix` is delivering  messages addressed to `opendkim@...`, which is not the same as `opendkim` process doing something.

Comment: @Paul I replied to you in an answer so the layout is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDKIM is not doing anything here anymore, but its user `opendkim` is getting *non-delivery notification*s a.k.a bounces that the Postfix is unable to deliver. There might be something in the queue that cannot get delivered because the SMTP port `25/tcp` is blocked by the ISP, and the bounces are not delivered either, because the Maildir does not exits.

You can list the messages in the queue using `sudo postqueue -p`, which should show:

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
123456789A!    1337 Fri Jan 05 13:37:00  ???@???
                                         opendkim@example.com
```

You could delete such messages altogether using `postsuper -d 123456789A` where `123456789A` is the Queue ID from the output of `postqueue -p`.

If new messages for `opendkim@example.com` appear in the log see a couple of lines above for the origin of the message.

Comment: Thank you so much @Esa Jokinaon, POSTFIX will not send on the server due to port 25 block, so I'll have to use an external service instead of running my own SMTP server.